# Click event lost after css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a laugh I have put a Google-esk barrel roll on one of my sites.
All works fine on the first click of the selected element, but it won't fire again after that.

I have tried `.click`, `.on('click', function() {})` and neither work.
Any ideas on how to fix and why this is happening?

[Basic jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5yqrxvkd/)

Source code example;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Roll Me
        </title>

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>

        <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#roll').on('click', function() {
                $('body').css({
                    "-moz-animation-name": "roll",
                    "-moz-animation-duration": "4s",
                    "-moz-animation-iteration-count": "1",
                    "-webkit-animation-name": "roll",
                    "-webkit-animation-duration": "4s",
                    "-webkit-animation-iteration-count": "1"
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="roll">
            <h1>click me</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the animation that you applied after it has finished and then re-add it on subsequent clicks.

```js
var $body = $('body');

$('#roll').on('click', function() {
    $body.addClass('barrel-roll');
});

$body.on('animationEnd webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd',function(e) {
    $body.removeClass('barrel-roll'); 
});
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes roll {
from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) }
to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) }
}

@-moz-keyframes roll {
from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) }
to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) }
}

@keyframes roll {
from { transform: rotate(0deg) }
to { transform: rotate(360deg) }
}

.barrel-roll {
 -webkit-animation-name: roll;   
 -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
 -moz-animation-name: roll;   
 -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="roll">
    <h1>click me</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not know that `animationEnd webkitAnimationEnd` were events... Interesting!

Answer (score 3):

That's because by that point the `body` element already has that CSS styling applied. The way to fix it is to remove the `style` properties from your `body` element:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').removeAttr('style');
}, 4000);
```

I've used `setTimeout` here to ensure the `style` attribute gets reset only after your animation has completed (after 4 seconds).

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5yqrxvkd/1/).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the click handler isn't firing. You can verify that with `console.log`. You need to reset the animation.

Answer (score 0):

After your animation completes, you have already set the animation! The only way to solve this is to remove it again, and then re-trigger it. The best way to do that, however, is CSS classes:

```js
var busy = false;

$('#roll').on('click', function() {
  if(busy) return;
  else busy = true;
  $('body').addClass("do-the-barrel-roll");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').removeClass("do-the-barrel-roll");
    busy = false;
  }, 2100);
});
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes roll {
from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) }
to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) }
}

@-moz-keyframes roll {
from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) }
to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) }
}

@keyframes roll {
from { transform: rotate(0deg) }
to { transform: rotate(360deg) }
}

body.do-the-barrel-roll {
  -webkit-animation: roll 2s;
  -moz-animation: roll 2s;
  animation: roll 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="roll">
    <h1>click me</h1>
</div>
```

Simple add the class and remove it after the time it takes for the animation to complete. Also, I added a busy to prevent multiple clicks from making this hell.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the css is applied. Since it is already applied then when it is applied again on the next click nothing happens. I have created something that works, adding a class then removing after a timeout that matches the animation length. https://jsfiddle.net/5yqrxvkd/3/

```
$('#roll').on('click', roll);

function roll(){
    $('body').addClass("animate");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").removeClass("animate");
    }, 4000);
}
```

There may be a better way using animate or something but I'm not that farmiliar with it.